# Google Cloud Function not working properly with firestore .get() - NODE JS

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm a novice web developer. I'm currently working on Firebase for a blog project.

This is my DB structure:

[image]

On my home page, I'm using this code to get the some latest posts from each of my category

```js
app.get('/test', (req, res) => {

  async function getDocument(db) {
    const ex = await db.collection('Posts').where('category', '==', 'Exercise').orderBy("artID", "asc").limit(4).get();
    const hl = await db.collection('Posts').where('category', '==', 'Health').orderBy("artID", "asc").limit(2).get();
    const fl = await db.collection('Posts').where('category', '==', 'Food & Lifestyle').orderBy("artID", "asc").limit(3).get();
    const md = await db.collection('Posts').where('category', '==', 'Mindfulness').orderBy("artID", "asc").limit(2).get();
    // const author = await db.collection('authors').doc(doc.data().author).get();
    return {
      ex: ex.data(),
      hl: hl.data(),
      fl: fl.data(),
      md: md.data()
    }
  }

  getDocument(db).then(function (data) {
    res.send(data);
  })
})
```

I've checked the code, and also made sure that the query is indexed in firestore.

But when I execute the function, the browser is throwing an error:

> Error: could not handle the request

and I get this error logged in my console.

> TypeError: ex.data is not a function
> at getDocument (/workspace/index.js:69:14)
> at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)

To get data from Firestore, placing a '.data()' function is needed.

Can somebody help me with where I'm typing the code wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the response of `await db.collection('Posts').where('category', '==', 'Exercise').orderBy("artID", "asc").limit(4).get();` is a `QuerySnapshot` - the filter will match more then one value and this is why you cannot access `data()` because there is more then one object.

You should do something like `ex.docs.map(doc => ({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() }))`

Comment: okay, I understand what I was doing wrong, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

As per @stefan-prokop-cz mentioned, you need to map each document snapshot from ex.docs. Also, you might wanna consider using `Promise.all()` to run these queries in parallel to improve computation time.

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply. Can you please guide me on how to do that?